# CSS @media to shift jquery banner is not working

Tags: html, css

(this is a part of my html, watch below comment)

(this is a part of my css)

@media screen and (min-width: 576px) {body { background: red; }

.banner { background: yellow; }

h1 { color: black; font-size: 60px; } }

everything in @media is working except .banner i don't know how to error

Comment: <body>
  <div class="banner">
    <h1>Hello World i'm learning css</h1>
  </div>
</body> (this is  a part of my html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the problem that you are facing. The codes are working on my side.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
body { background: red; }

.banner { background: yellow; }

h1 { color: black; font-size: 60px; } 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="banner"> <h1>Hello World i'm learning css</h1> </div>
</body>
</html>
```